# How to set mail send timeout?

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

So far here is my config in `common/config/main-local.php`

```
'transport' => [
'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
'host' => 'in-v3.mailjet.com',
'username' => 'myUsername',
'password' => 'myPass',
'port' => '465',
'encryption' => 'ssl',
],
```

How I can set timeout limit while sending an email?

I have no reference to set mail send timeout in Yii2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
'transport' => [
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'in-v3.mailjet.com',
    'username' => 'myUsername',
    'password' => 'myPass',
    'port' => '465',
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'timeout' => 2000 //in second
],
```

it's on `vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php::setTimeout()` you can check the value by

```
\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump(Yii::$app->mailer->transport->getTimeout(),10,1);
```